# Johnny get angry

Tags: lyrics, imperative-sentences

Here's a part of the lyrics of an old song of 1960s "Johnny get angry".
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wslyYxN8Nlg

> Oh, Johnny get angry, Johnny get mad
>
> Give me the biggest lecture I ever had

I wonder why she says "Johnny **get** angry" instead of "Johnny **gets** angry", or "Johnny **got** angry".
The same for **Give**.

Comment: Check out imperative sentences. ;)

Comment: @JersonZuleta I never thought it is imperative. But it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Original video link is now broken.  As of 1-27-2017, here is a replacement:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pI_nk0L-cF4

Answer (score 4):

The whole song is a woman complaining that her boyfriend doesn't act macho and aggressive enough. She implores him to tell her what to do, and to start fights with other guys out of jealousy.  She is telling him that he should get angry — it is a command, in imperative mood.

> *Johnny get angry, Johnny get mad*
>   *Give me the biggest lecture that I ever had*
>   *I want a brave man, I want a cave man*
>   *Johnny show me that you care, really care for me*